# how to add box shadow to after and before pseudo elements?

Tags: html, css

i am trying to do chat box....i want the same color and box shadow for pseudo elements as similar to the concern box ..i tried but its not working ....

here is my codepen link http://codepen.io/mgkrish/pen/qmEpeP?editors=1100

```css
.chat_other{
padding: 30px;

   
   padding-bottom: 15px; 
   padding-top: 15px;
display: flex;
   background-color: #ffffff;
  
   box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1),inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
   border-radius: 14px;
   width: 50%;
   position: relative;
   margin-left:30px;
}
    .chat_other:before {
           content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    bottom: -2px;
    left: -23px;
    height: 20px;
    border-left: 40px solid #E5E5EA;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 16px 14px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 9px;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -2px);
    }

  .chat_other:after {
       content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 4px;
    width: 26px;
    height: 20px;
    background: white;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 24px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-30px, -2px);
   
    /* border: 1px solid red; */}
.chat_self{
    background-color: #e6f7fd;
      border-radius: 14px;
      padding:30px;
         padding-top: 0;
           box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1),inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
           width: 50%;
                margin-right: 28px;
               padding-bottom: 15px;
               position: relative;
}
.chat_self:before {
  content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    bottom: -2px;
    right: -26px;
    height: 20px;
    border-right: 56px solid #e6f7fd;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px 19px;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -2px);
    border-bottom-right-radius: 43px;

}
.chat_self:after {
  content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;

    bottom: 4px;
    right: -59px;
    width: 29px;
    height: 20px;
    background: white;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 16px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 9px;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-30px, -2px);

}
```

```html
 <div class="chat_other">
                    
                    <p>Hey guys! Hope everything is doing great. Who’s up for a run today? I am really excited about the fact that all of you can join me for this.</p>
                    <p class="msg_time">12.47</p>
                   </div>

                     </div>
                     <div class="self"> 

 
                  
                   <div class="chat_self">
                    
                    <p>Hey guys! Hope everything is doing great. Who’s up for a run today? I am really excited about the fact that all of you can join me for this.</p>
                      <p class="msg_time">12.47 </p>
                   </div>

                     </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the `box-shadow` property?

Comment: yeah i tried but both are  not same...

Comment: Then it would be great if you posted an image/drawing of how it should look like

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByMDts1cKB-dbUtMWGotSVg2aWs 
     ..............image link..i am not able to share here